# display computed property in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding

I want to display first & last name of person in my form (xaml)
I use binding for getting person property from screen but I don't have computed property in screen because I don't know how can I create this one!! 
In that code I use only firstname but I want first and last name!!! :(

```
<telerik:Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding PersonelPropertiesTab,Source={StaticResource localResource}}"/>
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Screen.PersonelProperties}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.CurriculuminformationProperty.PersonelProperty,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         SelectedValue="Id" DisplayMemberPath="applicantfirstname"/>
                    <viewer:DescriptionViewer Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Description="{Binding PersonelPropertiesTab,Source={StaticResource localResource}}"/>
```

I read some article about thatthey are for lightswitch not silverlight.
Could you give me good references?

Comment: Why don't you make a backing field in our PersonelProperties called 'FullName' and have it return FirstName + LastName an then use that as your DisplayMemberPath?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `DisplayMemberPath`, you may set a `DataTemplate` for the ComboBox items. I haven't tested that with a RadComboBox, but I assume that it behaves like a standard ComboBox:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ...>
    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Inlines>
                    <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </TextBlock.Inlines>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```